# Cant find computermanegment by searching in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-search

I realy loved windows 7 but i use now windows 8 and one simple thing drives me nuts. Using windows 7 i was able to to press the windows key and then just type "computermanagement" to find the computermanagement console.

Now when i try to find the computermanagement console on windows 8.1 it does not find it and it drives me nuts. Im only able to open the computermanagement searching for compmgmt.msc or computer and then right click on computer and then press "manage".

Is it somehow possible to make windows find the management console using the keyword "computermanagement"?

Comment: If you are on the desktop mode is it not an option if you right click on the start menu ORB? (not in front of windows 8.1 at present so cannot check)

Comment: Yes you can use this way as well. Would be nice to do it the old way :P

Comment: Haha maybe they'll bring it back in Windows 10 :)

Comment: I hope so because it sould not be too hard to add this. I work a lot with notebooks not using any mouse and using the keyboard to find stuff is much faster than using the touchpad.

Comment: The closet I could get was by searching for **Administrative Tools**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s called “Computer Management”, with a space. I currently don’t have an English Windows 8 available but I can find it by its German name “Computerverwaltung” no problem.

Whether or not this works probably depends on whether you chose to show the “Administrative Tools” folder in your start menu/screen:

- On the start screen, bring up the charms bar (<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>)
- Select “Settings”, then “Tiles”
- Enable “Show administrative tools”

Don’t worry, they’re only visible in the complete view, they aren’t forced onto the customizable start screen.

Comment: Sound like what i want. I also use the german windows version. I cant find the settings you describe because when i select settings there is no "Tiles"

Comment: Thanks for the hint!!!!!! I found how to change the desired setting. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zxue/archive/2012/03/07/win8-howto-5-access-administrative-tools.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by:

- opening Run... (<kbd>Win+R</kbd>)
- typing in `compmgmt.msc`

Comment: i know. i can do this as well by only pressing the windows key and then type compmgmt.msc. You dont need to do win +r

Comment: Sure, I agree. Just a habit from being an admin (oldschool way).