# Settings app options don't appear in search results on win10

Tags: search, windows-10

When using search (by pressing the `win` button and writing my query) I don't seems to get results from the settings (the one with the gray background):

[image: Settings app]

For example, if I search for `mouse` I get the control panel `Mouse` settings:

[image: Search results for mouse]

But if I search for `windows update` or `bluetooth` I don't get any results:

[image: search results for windows update]

[image: Searh results for bluetooth]

Meanwhile, searching for cortana settings (which shows directly in the search window) seems to be fine:

[image: Search results for cortana]

I have rebuilt my index but it does not seem to have changed anything. It currently looks like this:

[image: Search index]

Anyone have any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: I'm hitting this same issue on a laptop I installed with Win 10 from scratch (not an upgrade). None of the Control Panel settings are searchable from the Start Menu or the Settings app search bar.

I have to go directly into Control Panel if I want to search for them.

It's probably even worse since "Mouse" doesn't even show up for me. Indexing is complete and enabled on all of C:\ drive.

Comment: Well, this started working for me 3 hours after my last comment. I did a dozen things trying to solve this issue, most noticeably:

1) I unchecked "Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties". Hit apply. I didn't wait for this to complete. Pressed cancel, checked it again and hit apply. Let it run until completion (~10 minutes).

2) I disabled all Cortana settings (Probably not related)

3) Afterwards, I rebooted my computer. Checked again after the reboot, still broken.

4) Checked again 3 hours later. Now all control panel items are searchable.

Comment: I tried unchecking/apply/rechecking/apply and a day after I don't see the settings in search. Will keep checking periodically to see if that changes.

Comment: A question though, were the settings you weren't seeing stuff only from the control panel (like `network and settings center` and `mouse`) or also things from the `settings` app (like `windows update`)? 

Can you see `windows update` in search at the moment?

Comment: It was everything in the control panel, including Windows update. Everything (+ Windows Update) is showing up now.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have worked for me so far then. Damn. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Threshold 2 (Windows 10 November update) seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common problem for people with **SSDs**. For some people reubilding the index works, but seeing as it did not work for you, try this:

1. Go to `This PC` and right click on whichever drive Windows is installed on. We will assume `C:\`
2. Right click and choose properties
3. At the bottom of the "General" tab, make sure `Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties` is checked.

> [image]

---

Also make sure under **Modify**, then `C:\` -->`Users` that all the users are selected:

[image]

It's possible somehow your user got de-selected.

---

Source: [Windows 8.1 Search not finding Control Panel Settings](https://superuser.com/a/698578/498587)

Note that answer 2 from the source will *not* work on Windows 10.

Comment: I checked, and the disk where windows is installed does have that tickbox checked. On indexing, modify, I could also see my user selected.

It's worth mentioning that control panel settings do appear (like display settings) - only things specific to the 'Settings' app do not (such as windows update)

Comment: Hmm. Just confirm for me typing [what I did here](http://i.imgur.com/PCTdDLI.png) produces nothing?

Comment: Correct, [this is my result](http://prntscr.com/8l0n6c) for the same query.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I have the same issue as Red

Comment: A solution that seems to work for most people has been posted here: http://superuser.com/questions/950102/what-do-i-have-to-index-in-order-to-search-the-windows-control-panel-in-win10/1182041#1182041

Answer (score 0):

(This would've been a comment but this is a new account, if I say something drastically wrong please do mention it)

The solution posted by Insane in this post, and [Wouter's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1182041) they linked in a comment didn't work for me, but what did work was opening `Indexing Options` -> `Advanced` -> `Troubleshoot search` and indexing, and selecting `Files, folders, apps or settings don't appear in results.`

I suspect my problem came from renaming my `users\username` folder recently, due to personal reasons, and while I expect that most users here will already know to check the troubleshooter, I didn't even know `Indexing Options` existed, so for other users like me I figured adding an answer couldn't hurt.
For most cases though, I expect other answers to work over mine (unless the troubleshooter is a new feature in which case try it first I guess?)