# Windows 10 search not working for Control Panel entries

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

My Windows 10 search can find the control panel, but not the entries inside it when searching from the start menu, e.g. "Sound", "System", "Mouse" and so on. It only works as a two step process of first searching for control panel and then entering the search there. "Windows Update" is not found as well. Is this by design or can I fix this somehow?

Comment: Nope. Not by design. A LOT of people have this issue. You can try to rebuild your index or [some of the things I mentioned here](http://superuser.com/a/978649/498587).

Comment: A solution that works for most users has been posted here: http://superuser.com/questions/950102/what-do-i-have-to-index-in-order-to-search-the-windows-control-panel-in-win10/1182041#1182041